# How to have radlistview paging maintain it's index when the back button is pressed?

Tags: asp.net, listview, telerik, pagination

The scenario is that i have a list view with paging. If the user is on page 4, then clicks a link, decides that its the wrong link, then hits the back button, the listview need to be displayed with the same sorting on page 4, just like he left it. Currently, it is resetting the sort and displaying on page 1.

I tried storing the current page index in a session when the index is changed, then setting it from the session in the prerender event, but then i get "page expired" errors. Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 0):

The back button operation can only be handled in client-side javascript, as the server-side code does not run.  For what you are trying to do, you'll want to check out these two resources (application history points):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488548.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488538.aspx